# jQuery on('submit'...) method doesn't work when mvc form is submitted in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble hitting the following jquery .on() method. My code simply won't access it:

```
$('#claimOrderForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have an mvc form and I'm submitting the form & saving it to the controller via javascript.  It saves fine, however in addition, I'd like to call the on(submit) event to prevent jquery from refreshing, but I've been unable to do so.

My code is as follows:

**View - Form start**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ClaimOrder", "ClaimOrders", null, ajaxOptions, new { @id = "claimOrderForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

**View - submit button**

*This submit button is hidden.  I handle the click event within javascript.  I did this because I want to handle all saving via jQuery dialog buttons*:

```
<input id="claimOrderSubmit" type="submit" style="display:none;"/>
```

**Javascript - Dialog**

```
claimOrder.dialogElem = claimOrder.findDialogContainer().dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                id: "claimOrderSaveButton",
                text: "Save",
                click: function () { claimOrder.SaveClaimOrder(); }
            },
            {
                id: "claimOrderCloseButton",
                text: "Close",
                click: function () { claimOrder.closeClick(); }
            }
            ],
            close: function () { clinicalReview.closeEvent(); }
    });
```

**Javascript - Save**

```
claimOrder.prototype.SaveClaimOrder = function () {
try {
    var methodName = "claimOrder.SaveClaimOrder ";
    var form = $("#claimOrderForm");
    var url = site.baseUrl + "ClaimOrders/ClaimOrder";
    form.prop("action", url);
    $("#claimOrderSubmit").click();
} catch (ex) {
    alert("error in " + methodName + ". ex:" + ex);
}
 };
```

Like I said, my javascript passes over to my mvc ActionResult fine & everything saves successfully, but I'm unable to hit that on(submit) event in my javascript.  Any idea how I can?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
$('#claimOrderForm').addEventListener('click',function(e){
//your function code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger the click event of that button as...

$("#claimOrderSubmit").trigger('click')..

i think this will do...